# file copy from remote client to NAS

Tags: backup, nas, remote

Is there an easy way to file-copy/backup (not a system image) all files of a remote system to a NAS, without having the users to stop working? I was thinking along the lines of Administrative Shares (\server\c$). I could access each user's system this way, and just copy all files to the NAS?

Would this work? Or would it work with some tool instead of through regular Windows copy? Would I run into trouble somewhere by copying system files or files in use? Do I need a tool that can work with volume shadow copies, and does that work with remote disks?

Thanks!